# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in .../search.php on line 46

Tags: php, json

Can anyone help me with this error? Been looking it at for a while but haven't been able to get it to work. Wrote this a while ago and felt like it worked when I last left it, but I haven't been able to run it when I revisited it. Thanks for all the help.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/search/views/layouts/search.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/search/views/layouts/search.php on line 46

Line 46 is the foreach line 4th from the last line of code.

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'search/scripts/JSON.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'search/scripts/search_fns.php');

$searchquery = urlencode(isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : "news");

// Google Search API

$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
. "q="
. $searchquery
."&key=ABQIAAAAYIeqEnf9yNjBzcHJK7yDdhSklBzi76D_F0lniPI7JR27aK7eCBSU-xpNs1axVS45y_PX_7_ibsScUA&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS&rsz=filtered_cse";

// sendRequest
// note how referer is set manually
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://localhost");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// process the JSON string
$json = new Services_JSON;
$json = $json->decode($body);

$formattedresults = "";
$rating = "";

$search = $searchquery;

?>
<style type="text/css">
td img {display: block;}
</style>
<div id="main">

<?php
foreach($json->responseData->results as $searchresult)
{
if($searchresult->GsearchResultClass == 'GwebSearch')
{
```

Comment: basic debugging: var_dump($json);

Answer (score 0):

Probably it returned an empty response.
Before using foreach it's useful to test the variable using `is_object($json->responseData)`. I would also check if the property 'results' exist with `property_exists($json, 'results')`